# How to synchronize ubuntu time with the currenttime

Tags: date, http, ubuntu, time, http-status-code-404

index.js:165  Uncaught (in promise) Error: Server returned an error:
Code: 400 (Bad Request)
Body: Specified ingress_expiry not within expected range:
Minimum allowed expiry: 2024-02-21 09:25:55.369426445 UTC
Maximum allowed expiry: 2024-02-21 09:31:25.369426445 UTC
Provided expiry:        2024-02-21 10:40:11.509 UTC
Local replica time:     2024-02-21 09:25:55.369426901 UTC

```
at HttpAgent.call (index.js:165:1)
at async caller (actor.js:174:43)
at async handleClick (Faucet.jsx:8:1)
```

I am getting this error while i am deploying my app and running my local server.Then i also made the changes like using sudo apt-get install ntp and sudo hwclock -s to synchronize my ubuntu time with my systemtime but it is still not working.My ubuntu terminal is not synchronizing with the currenttime. and after using this i redployed my app and still it is showing the above error.May i know how can i resolve this..

How to synchronize my ubuntutime with my currentsystem time?